# Can I call(invoke) a ruby factorial method using the mathematical notation?

Tags: ruby, operator-overloading, overriding, factorial

I have a function to give me the factorial of a number

```
class Integer
  def fact
    (1..self).reduce(:*) || 1
  end
end
```

I'd like to know how can I call this method using the Mathematical notation
 of Factorial " N!"

I've tried

```
class Integer
  def !
    (1..self).reduce(:*) || 1
  end
end
```

and another things, but none of the them work.

Answer (score 2):

You can only overload operators that already exist. There is no ruby operator in which `!` is used as a suffix.

Ruby does, however, have the logical `not` operator that uses `!` as a prefix. This is in fact what you have overloaded.

Based on your code:

```
!4 # => 24
```

This is not advisable, of course, but is a bit educational on how overloading works in general.

Alternatively, this is a bit closer to convention:

```
4.! # => 24
```